# FlatList Dynamic Height Sizing

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-flatlist

I have an AutoComplete Box which gives me a list of autocomplete items. I display the items in FlatList, I also have a border around the FlatList. My code is given below: -

```
render(){
return (
  <View>
    <TextInput
       clearButtonMode="while-editing"
       onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
       value={this.state.searchText}
       onSubmitEditing={this.onTextSubmitted}
       placeholder="Find..." />
       {this.state.data.length > 0 &&
        <FlatList
           style={styles.list}
           keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
           data={this.state.data}
           ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
           keyExtractor={item => item.properties.id}
           renderItem={this.renderItem} />});
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
list: {
    borderWidth: 16,
    borderColor: colors.searchBorder,
  },
});
```

How can I increase/decrease the size of the FlatList with the number of list items, (I think the border is the reason behind this error).

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: How is it displaying  the list currently and how do you want it? If you can show a screenshot

Comment: Have you fixed this. I am also having the same issue

Comment: Did you find a solution this problem? Please share

Answer (score 90):

Add `flexGrow: 0` to your list style.

Comment: This makes my list not display any data at all, I really need this behaviour (resizing the list depending on size content) though!

Comment: @Sami Do the children have absolute positioning? You might try setting the heights of the rows, or even use `getItemLayout` (not 100% sure it will work with flex: 0, but worth a try) https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout

Answer (score 3):

**add flexGrow: 0, and minHeight as per your requirement**

```
 container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexGrow: 0,
        minHeight: 70,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',          
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solutions above not work in my case.

The solution, for me, was to wrap the FlatList into a ScrollView like this :

```
<ScrollView>
  <FlatList
      data={this.state.listItem}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

The dynamic height will be managed by the ScollView parent.

See the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview).

Comment: This should not be the right answer as per 2020. You will get an warning: "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead. "

Answer (score -1):

The border is just an indicator of boundaries of your current FlatList component. If you want the list to grow and shrink try adding `flex: 1` to your list style property.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    borderWidth: 16,
    borderColor: colors.searchBorder,
    flex: 1
  },
})
```

Comment: using the `flex` shorthand doesn't work, you have to manually specify the flexGrow attribute (i.e. `flexGrow: 0`)