# Dynamically size FlatList to wrap content

Tags: android, react-native, jsx

To preface, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057598/flatlist-dynamic-height-sizing), but it didn't work for me. Using that makes my list not show up at all, but here's what I want to achieve:

I'm working on a comment system, where I want the newest comment to show up at the bottom and when you open the screen, you automatically are on the bottom of the list so you can see the most recent comment. Easy, just reverse the list that you hand over to the list and scroll down to the bottom in onLayout and onContentSizeChange.

The problem with that is that the comments don't have the same length, of course, so the elements of the FlatList are dynamically sized, which makes the scrolling down a bit janky.

The other solution would be to use the 'inverted' prop, but here, the FlatList looks like this when there are less comments than what's needed to fill up the screen:

[image]

I colored the background of the FlatList black to see what's going on.

Is there any way I can make the FlatList wrap the content and extend with it until it reaches screen height?

Here is my code for the list:

```js
  <View flex={1} backgroundColor={'white'}>
        <TabHeader store={store}/>
        <FlatList
          inverted
          ref={ref => store.flatList = ref}
          data={elements}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => (
            <CommentRow
              item={item}
              index={index}
            />
          )}
          ListFooterComponent={() => <TabFooter store={store} />}
          onEndReachedThreshold ={0.1}
          onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
            loadNext();
          }}
          style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}
        />
        <Row h={0.3}/>
        <TextInput
          ref={ref => store.textInput = ref}
          multiline
          blurOnSubmit
          underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
          onFocus={store.hideTabs}
          autoFocus={store.focusOnStart}
          onEndEditing={store.showTabs}
          onSubmitEditing={store.submitComment}
          value={store.userComment}
          onChangeText={store.changeText}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          autoCorrect={false}
          style={{marginLeft: 20}}
        />
        <Row h={0.3} />
      </View>
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `flex: 1`? are you trying to have the comment show up at the top if there aren't enough comments?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I need the comment being on top and then populate the list downwards. Flex: 1 doesn't do anything, unfortunately, I've tried all combinations of flex: 1 and flexGrow: 1 and stuff like that, but it won't budge :(

Comment: understood can you please show me the whole component? Specifically the view that wraps the `FlatList`

Comment: For example: http://prntscr.com/kd8r9n Even though the `FlatList` is inverted it's still stuck to the top, which is what I'm assuming you want to do.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I've updated the code snippet above!