# Expo - Nested horizontal Flatlist dynamic height

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, height, react-native-flatlist

I'm currently developing a list with exercises. A new feature should be that a certain exercise can have replacements.

All exercises are displayed in a flatList vertically.

The replacements of an exercise should be displayed horizontal. That works fine.

**Issue:**

Each exercise can have a different amount of sets that are listed. As you can see below. When the user is scrolling horizontally the height of the nested FlatList doesn't change accordingly.

[Working vertical list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJtEq.png)

[Not working horizontal list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SESm.png)

**WorkoutExerciseList (Vertical scroll flatlist)**

```
  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({
      item,
      drag,
      isActive,
    }: RenderItemParams<WorkoutExercise | WorkoutExercise[]>) => {
      if (Array.isArray(item) && item.length >= 2) {
        return (
          <ReplacementExercisesList
            items={item}
            drag={drag}
            displaySetFinishedHeaderIcon={displaySetFinishedHeaderIcon}
          />
        );
      } else if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        return (
          <WorkoutExercisesListItem
            {...item[0]}
            drag={drag}
            displaySetFinishedHeaderIcon={displaySetFinishedHeaderIcon}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <WorkoutExercisesListItem
            {...item}
            drag={drag}
            displaySetFinishedHeaderIcon={displaySetFinishedHeaderIcon}
          />
        );
      }
    },
    []
  );

 <DraggableFlatList
      contentContainerStyle={{
        // flexGrow: 1,
        // flex: 1,
        paddingBottom: 160,
      }}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
      // style={{ flex: 1 }}
      data={workoutExercises}
      onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
          return item[0].id;
        } else {
          return item.id;
        }
      }}
    />
```

**ReplacementExerciseList - Horizontal scroll**

```
 <Animated.FlatList
        data={items}
        ref={ref}
        // contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <WorkoutExercisesListItem
            drag={drag}
            {...item}
            index={index}
            displaySetFinishedHeaderIcon={displaySetFinishedHeaderIcon}
            isReplacementExercise={true}
            computeHeight={computeListHeight}
          />
        )}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        // onViewableItemsChanged={handleVieweableItemsChanged}
        scrollEventThrottle={32}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        horizontal={true}
        initialScrollIndex={activeIndex}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        bounces={false}
        pagingEnabled={true}
      />
```

I tried to calculate the height of each item in the ReplacementExerciseList (Horizontal) and set a dynamic height for the list, whenever the active horizontal index changes. But this ends up in an Error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **minHeight** and **flexGrow: 0** [(here you can find)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057598/flatlist-dynamic-height-sizing) to handle dynamic height but I would recommend using [RecyclerView](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview) as this have better options for dynamic height plus better performance with dynamic sizings.

Comment: Where exactly would you place minHeight and FlexGrow. To the Parent FlatList or the horizontal one? Should i use style or contentContainerStyle prop?

Comment: Also my list needs to have the same height as my visual item. Thats not really the case in your given stackoverflow post :)

Comment: Your `height` must be an integer value instead of NAN.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the second horizontal flatList. Instead i render only ONE list item. When the user is switching to another item i will set a new index. The item always renders the data of the selected index:

```
  const onSelectReplacementExercise = useCallback((itemIndex: any) => {
    console.log("itemIndex", itemIndex);
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
    setActiveIndex(itemIndex);
  }, []);

 <WorkoutExercisesListItem
        {...items[activeIndex]}
        displaySetFinishedHeaderIcon={displaySetFinishedHeaderIcon}
        isReplacementExercise={true}
      />
```

onSelectReplacementExercise is called by my switch menu.